# Can AzureReader2 read Azure storage configuration settings from the service config rather than the web.config?

Tags: imageresizer

Is there any way for the AzureReader2 plugin to read its connection string and endpoint config values from the service config file rather than just the web.config?

The problem is that we build Azure package files (.cspkg) and web.config files are embedded within the package.  Therefore we strive to keep our web.config files constant across all different deployments (test, dev, and production).  We normally deploy using a package file and a service config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Install AzureReader 2 via code during application startup instead, and you can pass it the connection string directly:

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc["endpoint"] = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/";
nvc["connectionString"] = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
new AzureReader2Plugin(nvc).Install(Config.Current);
```